# Pandas Resample Not Returning 'on=' column in aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, resample

I have three pandas Dataframe with 3 features:

```
Date In, Date Out, Status
```

Date In/Out are timestamps. Status is a text field.

I want to know how many came in on every month and how many that went out in the same month.

I used:

```
d = df.resample('M', on='Date In').count()
```

This returns the count of Date Out matching every month of Date In's resample. However, it seems to *remove* the Date In column from the output, making it the index. This makes

```
d['Date In']
```

not possible to get the count of `Date In` for that month. Moreover, if I had more columns, this would also show the counts of those *relative* to Date In. This is what makes the .resample() method so effective.

I have recently updated pandas and I think this is one of the things they changed in the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `groupby` like this:

```
in_counts = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date In', freq='M')).size()
out_counts = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date Out', freq='M')).size()

counts_df = pd.DataFrame({'In Count': in_counts, 'Out Count': out_counts})
counts_df = counts_df.reset_index()
counts_df = counts_df.rename(columns={'Date In': 'Month'})

print(counts_df)
```

I hope this answers your requirement.